# FBAndroid-2.1.apk missing

Tags: android, facebook

As per the instructions mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
to install Facebook SDK. 
When I download the facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2 boundle, bin folder is empty. I can't begin to develop.

To install APK with the help of adp , I am using the following command :
adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\bin\FBAndroid-2.1.apk

It is throwing exception-- can't find

This the because FBAndroid-2.1.apk is missing in the zip downloaded from https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.zip

Can anyone please share the missing file so that i can complete my installation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try an older version e.g. the 3.0.1 version:
https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Please try again, it should be updated now.